# Error al compilar una lista en java

Tags: java, funciones, método, compilar

es mi primera vez en Stackoverflow y espero me puedan ayudar. Estoy en cursos de Java y estamos en la parte de creacion de listas, tengo esta clase (Lista.java) la cual contiene lo siguiente:

```
public class Lista{

  Node inicio;
  int tamanio=0;
  /** se procede a crear una lista vacia**/
  public Lista(){
    inicio=null;
  }

  public boolean esVacia(){
    return(inicio==null);
  }

  //insercion de elementos a la Lista
  public void agregarAlFinal(int valor){
    //se crea una nueva variable de tipo Node
    Node nuevo = new Node();
    //se le agrega un valor al nodo creado
    nuevo.setDato(valor);
    //se verifica si la lista esta esVacia
    if (esVacia()) {
      //si la lista esta vacia...el nodo ingresado pasara a ser el inicio de la misma
      inicio = nuevo;
      //de lo contrario, se tiene que recorrer la lista hasta el ultimo nodo ingresado
      //y de ahi se agrega el nuevo
    } else {
      // se crea una copia de la Lista
      Node aux = inicio;
      //se usa un while para recorrer la lista hasta encontrar el final
      //se usa la copia del nodo original para esto
      while(aux.getLink() != null){
        //la copia del nodo pasa a ser el nodo siguiente
        aux = aux.getLink();
      }
      //se agrega el nuevo nodo al final de la Lista
      aux.setLink(nuevo);
    }
    //se incrementa el tamanio de la Lista
    tamanio++;
  }

  //metodo para ingresar un nodo al inicio de la Lista
  public void agregarAlInicio(int valor){
    //se define un nuevo nodo
    Node nuevo = new Node();
    //se le agregar valor al nodo
    nuevo.setDato(valor);
    //se verifica si esta vacia la Lista
    if (esVacia()) {
      //si esta vacia, el nodo ingresado sera el inicio de la Lista
      inicio = nuevo;
      //de lo contrario, el nodo ingresado sera ingresado antes que el agregarAlInicio
      //para convertirse en el nuevo inicio
    } else {
      //une el nodo ingresado con la lista existente
      nuevo.setLink(inicio);
      //se renombra el nodo ingresado como el inicio de la Lista
      inicio=nuevo;
    }
    //se incrementa la Lista
    tamanio++;
  }
//metodo para encontrar el valor que esta dentro de una posicion dada en la Lista
  public int getValor(int posicion){
    //hay que verificar que la posicion que se manda es mayor o igual que el indice 0 y menor que el numero de
    //elementos que hay en la Lista
    if (posicion>=0 && posicion<= tamanio) {
      //hay que consultar si la posicion que se mando es el inicio de la Lista
      if (posicion==0) {
        //si es asi, retorna el valor del inicio de la Lista
        return inicio.getDato();
        //de lo contrario
      } else {
        //se crea una copia de la Lista
        Node aux = inicio;
        //se recorre la lista hasta la posicion que se mando
        for (int i=0;i<posicion-1 ;i++ ) {
          //la copia del nodo pasa a ser el nodo siguiente
          aux = aux.getLink();
        }
        //retorna el valor del nodo
        return aux.getDato();
      }
      //si la posicion enviada no esta en la lista, devuelve un valor no valido en la Lista
    } else {
      return -10000;
    }
  }

  //metodo para encontrar el numero de indice de un valor que ya esta dentro de la Lista
  public boolean buscar(int referencia){
    //crear una copia de la Lista
    Node aux = inicio;
    //se crea una variable de tipo booleano para ver si el valor existente
    //y se inicializa en falso
    boolean encontrado = false;
    //se recorre la lista hasta encontrar el elemento que se solicito o hasta llegar
    //al final de la Lista
    while(aux !=null && encontrado != true){
      //se verifica si el valor ingresado que esta representado como "referencia"
      //es igual al valor del encontrado
      if (referencia == aux.getDato()) {
        //cambia el valor de la variable encontrado
        encontrado=true;
      }//de lo contrario se avanza al siguiente nodo
      else {
        aux =aux.getLink();
      }
    }
    //retorna el resultado de la variable encontrado
    return encontrado;
  }

  //metodo para eliminar un elemento de la lista en base al dato que contiene (por referencia)

  public void removerPorReferencia(int referencia){
    //se consulta si el valor de referencia esta en la Lista
    if (buscar(referencia)) {
      //si el valor se encuentra una vez ejecutado el metodo buscar(referencia),
      //se tiene que consultar si el nodo a eliminar es el primero
      if (inicio.getDato()==referencia) {
        //entonces el primer nodo apuntaria al siguiente nodo
        inicio = inicio.getLink();
        //de lo contrario se creara una copia de la lista para poder trabajar en la copia
      } else {
        Node aux = inicio;
        //se tiene que recorrer la lista hasta llegar al nodo que esta antes del ingresado
        //como referencia
        while(aux.getLink() != referencia ){
          aux = aux.getLink();
        }
        //Guarda el nodo siguiente del nodo a eliminar
        Node siguiente = aux.getLink().getLink();
        //enlaza el nodo anterior al que se va a eliminar con
        //el siguiente despues del que se va a eliminar
        aux.setLink(siguiente);
      }
      //disminuye el tamanio de la Lista
      tamanio--;
    }
  }

  public void print(){
    Node aux = inicio;
    for (int i=0;i<tamanio ;i++ ) {
      System.out.println(aux.data);
      aux=aux.link;
    }
  }

}
```

El problema es que al compilarlo me indica un error ya que no reconoce el método `getValor()` dentro del método `removerPorReferencia()`. Me da lo siguiente:

> error: cannot find symbol
>           while(aux.getLink().getValor() != referencia ){
>                              ^   symbol:   method getValor()   location: class Node 1 error

el metodo `getValor()` lo puedo llamar dentro de otros métodos sin problema y me devuelve valores sin problema.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

De antemano gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Hola, podrias proporcionar el codigo de la clase Nodo, me va a servir para analizar el problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tratas de acceder al metodo getValor() de la clase Lista a través del objeto aux de la clase Node, justamente por eso es el error, el método no se encuentra en la clase Node.